# Interesting problem concerned with updating a value in Presto sql

Tags: sql, algorithm, hiveql, presto

I am trying to solve the below problem for quite a while now in Presto sql but no approach seems to work.

Suppose I have below table with two columns. *X* and  *Y*. *Output* is what I want.

```
X       Y   Output
dummy   1   1
dummy   2   1
dummy   3   3
dummy   4   3
dummy   5   5
```

**The logic is, I set the Y value in the first row as start and look ahead, if all the subsequent rows are within start + 2 then I assign the first row value as output, otherwise I update the start value with the Y value of the current row.**

For example, our initial start value is 1 since first and second row has value less than 3 (start + 2), so we assign the output the value 1, but since 3 is not within the criteria start value gets updated to 3.

Is it even possible in presto sql? Is there any scalable workaround for this problem?

Comment: How do you know the order of the induvidual rows? I quess you need some kind of index column?

Comment: @Aldert the order is decided by the Y column. It is same as the ascending order of Y column where ties are broken randomly.

Comment: Still, you are looking at this as if it is an excel sheet. Why Y=1 is the start of your calculation? If I take 2 as start, the outcome is different..

Comment: So the first step is to order by Y asc. If we do that the start of the calculation and hence output is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

**Update: I have found a way to achieve the desired output with below steps.**

1. I use array_agg with distinct. I also make an additional column start which contains the minimum value in form of an array.The output at this point will look like below.

```
X      A            start
dummy [1,2,3,4,5]   [1]
```

2. At this point, I use reduce function of presto. I take the last element from the start and compare it with the current element of array. If the difference is <2 I update start by appending the last element of the array else I use the current element of the array and this is stored in b.

```
reduce(A, start, case when x - s[cardinality(s)] < 2 then s || s[cardinality(s)] else s || x end, s-> s) as b
```

The final output shall be like below.

```
X      A            start   b
dummy [1,2,3,4,5]   [1]     [1,1,3,3,5]
```

3. Next step is obvious, we simply explode b after using array_distinct and join with proper conditions.